# Encrypt config file section when using Visual Studio 2010 'Web Deploy'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the Visual Studio 2010 'publish web' dialog to deploy my site using 'Web Deploy' as explained on this link http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx

In my web config file I would like to encrypt a section and was thinking of using 
either the -pe or -pef option of the aspnet_regiis.exe utility which exists in the framework folder.

What I don't understand is whether I can get 'Web Deploy' to invoke aspnet_regiis.exe on the server after deployment or whether it is normal practice to encrypt the file not using machine keys and deploy this?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Ideally I would to continue to use 'Web Deploy' for convenience reasons.

Answer (score -1):

I've always run this manually on the server and would consider that the normal practice. 
However - you can include a runCommand though using a format similar to:

http://forums.iis.net/p/1173149/1961663.aspx

Also ensure you are running under correct permissions.

Comment: Why the downvote? - This is a standard security practice and it confirmed the scenario in OP